# I need to connect my MacBook Air to a specific MAC address when I use an xfinity hotspot

Tags: network, wifi

I would like my MacBook to connect to a specific MAC address whenever I select a given SSID. So if there are six xfinitywifi SSID in range, I want to be able to choose to always connect to one via MAC address.

**PLEASE NOTE I AM RUNNING OS X YOSEMITE 10.10.5, THAT MEANS THAT OLDER SOLUTIONS LIKE: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport --associate=XXX --bssid=YYY DO NOT SEEM TO WORK.

As background: There are a number of hotspots nearby, all with the same default SSID of the Internet provider (xfinitywifi). However, when I connect, I receive responses from several of these hotspots, and I get kicked off the Internet as a consequence. I want to always connect to only one of these. I am running OS X Yosemite v 10.10.5. On my PC I can use the app NetSetMan to accomplish this, though I am told on my MacBook I can probably accomplish this through the terminal. Either terminal or software suggestions are welcome.

For the benefit of other people with a similar problem -- that is, connecting to xfinitywifi and getting repeatedly kicked off after a couple of minutes -- this has caused many people hours and hours of confusion and frustration, based on a review of message boards. However, this problem is often a consequence of your computer or other device calling to xfinitywifi, and multiple xfinitywifi hotspots responding. There are two ways I am aware of to solve this problem: (1) the best way I have found is to identify the BSSID of the hotspot you want to connect to, and connect directly, or (2) you can walk over to your preferred hotspot and connect from as close to it as possible -- this can work because if the signal is strong enough, your device will connect to the strong network and (for whatever reason, I am not a network engineer) you will not experience the interruptions.

For a Windows user, I use the free app NetSpot to ID the various hotspots, gauge their strength, and choose the BSSID of the one I want to connect to, and then I use NetSetMan to connect directly. Now I want to do the same with my MacBook. I hope this helps.

Comment: NetSpot ID is also available as a fee Mac download.  Will that work?

Comment: perhaps a silly question, but this is not your own wireless network, therefore you can't change the name? Seems like a really stupid problem needlessly created by Xfinity.